# Question about oxygen and beta carbons in chemical shifts

Tags: spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

[image]
Why do the methylene protons that are attached to the beta carbon for the ester group have a chemical shift of +0.6 from oxygen, whereas the methyl protons attached to the beta carbon for the ester group have a chemical shift of +0.5 from oxygen? In other words, why is the oxygen treated as an ester for the methylene protons, but treated as an ether for the methyl protons?

What am I missing? How do I determine when to interpret the beta carbon as an ester or an ether when the carbon is connected to an ester group?

Comment: What do you mean by +0.6/+0.5 from oxygen?

Comment: if an alpha proton is neighboring an oxygen of an ether group, the effect on the alpha proton is +2.5. if it's neighboring an oxygen of an ester, the effect is +3.0. if a beta proton is 1/5th that of an alpha proton, the ether should give +0.5 to chemical shift, and the ester, +0.6. the methyl groups and the bottom methylene group both look like beta protons for ester to me, but only the methylene group is considered so?

Comment: Are you  talking about Shoolery increments (and relatives)?

Comment: Which beta-carbons? There is only an alpha-carbon on the ester.

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps you are misunderstanding some basic principles of determining chemical shifts. I have no idea where you are getting your +0.5/+0.6 factors

Chemical shifts are a product of all contributing functional groups; those that contribute to the local electron density either through direct electronic effects or through steric effects. Looking at the 3 proton environments, we can roughly predict their chemical shift using additive tables (I use [Pretsch, Buhlmann and Badertscher](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-540-93810-1)).

First, let's look at the types of protons. Methyl protons and methylene protons do not have the same basis chemical shift to work from when doing additive calculations; the shielding from a C-C bond is not the same as for a C-H bond, and so the local shielding for the proton of interest will be different. Generally, when doing additive calaculations for chemical shifts, we can use the starting shifts of 0.86 (-CH3), 1.37 (-CH2-) and 1.50 (>CH-).

For this molecule, there are 3 proton environments. I have shown their predicted chemical shifts below.

[image]

For methyl protons at site 1

- Each -CH3 proton is alpha to a quaternary C, beta to an oxygen-bound ester and beta to a carbon-bound ester.
- So that gives us 0.86+0.05+0.44+0.07= 1.42ppm

For methylene protons at site 2

- alpha to a ether oxygen, alpha to a quaternary carbon, beta to an oxygen-bound ester and beta to 2 methyl groups.
- So that gives: 1.37+2.04+0+0.24-0.06-0.06= 3.53ppm

For methylene protons at site 3

- alpha to ether oxygen and alpha to carbonyl-bound ester. The ester oxygen is taken into consideration as part of the ester group as a whole. Also, the atom on the other side of the ether (in this case the carbon) is taken into consideration - The only important thing here is whether the ester is oxygen-bound or carbonyl-bound.
- So, that gives us 1.37+2.04+0.92= 4.33ppm

Comment: the values are from my textbook. i had erroneously assumed these values were established benchmarks, but the values you've provided are so different from what is shown in my book i now see that is not the case. (the answer in my book is presented as thus, hence the confusion: imgur.com/a/0ReHP). when i did the problem originally, i got the correct answers for the methylene protons, but answered 1.5 ppm rather than 1.4 ppm for the methyl protons using the information presented in my textbook. thank you for the answer, however, as i see the reason is much more complicated than my book presents.